# Filling missing months when calculating year to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table cumulative year todate

```
year month qty_ytd
2017   01    20
2017   02   30
2018   01    50
```

I need to fill gabs missing months in the same year till december:

Result as example:

```
year month qty_ytd
2017   01    20
2017   02   30
2017   03   30
.....
2017   07   30
2017   12   30

2018   01    50
2018   02    50
....
2018   12    50
```

How to do it? I did'nt figure out how to fill the missing months?

Comment: What is your question here? You've stated what you want but not asked anything. What have you tried? There's plenty of examples on how to do this. Personally I recommend a tally or calendar table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cross join` to generate the rows and `cross apply` to get the data:

```
select y.y, v.m, t.qty_ytd
from (select distinct year from t) y cross join
     (values (1), (2), (3), (4), . . . (12)) v(m) outer apply
     (select top (1) t.*
      from t
      where t.year = y.year and
            t.month <= y.m
      order by t.m desc
     ) t;
```

Assuming `qty_ytd` is non-decreasing, it might be more performant to use window functions:

```
select y.y, v.m,
       max(t.qty_ytd) over (partition by y.y order by v.m) as qty_ytd
from (select distinct year from t) y cross join
     (values (1), (2), (3), (4), . . . (12)) v(m) left join
     t
     on t.year = y.year and
        t.month = v.m;
```

Comment: In the first query that you write, I need to add m from (select distinct year,m from t) y cross join, right ?

Comment: @csharp . . . No.  That was a type.  It should be (and now is) `v.m`.

Comment: in the first query I need to change  `where t.year = y.year and
            t.m <= y.m`  to  `where t.year = y.year and
            t.m <= v.m`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to compute delta, add dummy zero deltas, restore running total. I've changed source data to show more common case

```
create table #t
(
 year int,
 month int, 
 qty_ytd int
);

insert #t(year, month, qty_ytd )
values
(2017,   01,   20),
(2017,   02,   30),
(2018,   04,   50) -- note month
;

select distinct year, month, sum(delta) over(partition by year order by  month)
from (
    -- real delta
    select year, month, delta = qty_ytd - isnull(lag(qty_ytd) over (partition by year order by month),0)
    from #t
    union all
    -- tally dummy delta
    select top(24) 2017 + (n-1)/12, n%12 + 1 , 0
    from 
    ( select row_number() over(order by a.n) n
      from
      (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) a(n),
      (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) b(n)
    ) c
)d
order by year, month;
```